# How to use the DateTimeFormatterBuilder for custom date fromatting in Java 8?

Tags: date, time, calendar, java-8

My requirement is to format a date like "New Year in "+someYear+" was on "+someDay.
How can we achieve this using the DateTimeFormatterBuilder?

Comment: Is a builder necessary here? Maybe you can also use a pattern like "'New Year in' yyyy 'was on' EEEE"? (literals can be escaped by apostrophs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this as follows:

```
    DateTimeFormatter customFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendLiteral("New Year in ")
        .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR)
        .appendLiteral(" was on  ")
        .appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK,TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE)
        .toFormatter(); 

    LocalDate ld1  = LocalDate.of(2016, Month.JANUARY, 1); 
    String formatted = ld1.format(customFormatter); 
    System.out.println(formatted);
```

However, i think it has one flow that we need to explicitly pass the exact new year date. But, it is resolving my issue of specifically parsing/formatting the date.